# Matching Cubic Bézier to match Cubic Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, bezier-curve

I have a series of cubic polynomials that are being used to create a trajectory. Where some constraints can be applied to each polynomial, such that these 4 parameters are satisfied.
-Initial Position
-final Position
-Initial Velocity
-final Velocity

The polynomials are pieced together such that the ends of one polynomial are identical to the beginnings of the next to preserve continuity.

I instead want to represent these polynomials as cubic Bézier curves.

**How would I find the x,y position of each control point for the cubic Bézier curves, such that it matches the curvature of the cubic polynomial.**

Here is what I have so far, made in desmos.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/agsywptfno

Currently the bezier curve is defined as a binomial, with a polynomial for X and or Y
e.g. Bezier = (X(t), Y(t))

Answer (score 0):

First control point = initial position (obviously).

Second control point = initial position plus 1/3 of initial velocity.

Third control point = final position minus 1/3 of final velocity.

Fourth control point = final position (obviously).

Comment: This wasn't quite the answer, but it did get me to the answer! Thank you bubba or your insight.

This was the solution that worked for me for the second and third control point. 
Where P1 P2 P3 P4 are the control points V0 and Vf are initial and final velocities at points P1 and P4

P2.x = (P4.x - P1.x)/3
P2.y = (P1.y + V0*(P4.x - P1.x)/3

P3.x = (P4.x-P1.x) - (P4.x - P1.x)/3
P3.y = P4.x - Vf*((P4.x-P1.x) - (P4.x - P1.x)/3)/2

There's quite a bit of simplification that this needs, it's extremely verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Where P1 P2 P3 P4 are the control points V0 and Vf are initial and final velocities at points P1 and P4 P2.x = (P4.x - P1.x)/3 P2.y = (P1.y + V0*(P4.x - P1.x)/3 P3.x = (P4.x-P1.x) - (P4.x - P1.x)/3 P3.y = P4.x - Vf*((P4.x-P1.x) - (P4.x - P1.x)/3)/2

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nhofdaedoa) is the link if you're a visual person like me. The dotted orange lines are always 1/3 of the way to the next point or previous point.